# Backbone.js sync using native websockets

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, websocket, synchronization

I'm attempting to override the default Backbone.sync function with one that syncs via WebSockets. So far I've managed to successfully send a fetch request to the server using the code below but I don't know how to catch the response.

I've seen people suggest resetting the sockets onmessage event handler each time but I can't help but think that this might cause the responses to go out of sync if a lot of data is requested at once (if one request takes a long time to respond).

Are there any examples of how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

```
var app = app || {};

function fnSync (sMethod, oModel, oOptions) {
    var bSuccess,
        sResponse;

    bSuccess = false;

    switch (sMethod) {
        case "read":
            if (oModel.id !== undefined) {
                app.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "method": "get",
                    "url": oModel.url,
                    "id": oModel.get("_id")
                }));
            } else {
                app.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "method": "get",
                    "url": oModel.url
                }));
            }
            bSuccess = true;
            break;

        default:
            throw "Backbone.sync doesn't know how to " + sMethod;
            bSuccess = false;
            break;
    }

    (bSuccess) ? oOptions.success() : oOptions.error();
}

(function () {

    app.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3001");
    app.socket.onopen = function () {
        Backbone.sync = fnSync;

        app.router = new app.Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    app.socket.onmessage = function (oMessage) {
        //console.log("Socket message", oMessage.data);
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [Backbone.WS project](https://github.com/ydaniv/backbone-ws) for using Backbone resources over native WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

The technique we use involves using [Backbone-relational](http://backbonerelational.org/) and `Model.findOrCreate({id: response.id})` in the `socket.onmessage` handler to dispatch updates with a simple `model.set()` when we find it.

In situation's where we don't have ids we use client-only temp-ids that the API is designed to ignore and return as-is so we can distinguish and track the responses.